# processing 1GB file pyspark in my HDP cluster java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

**Code**

```
$pyspark
$json_file = sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles('/user/admin/emp/*').values())
```

**Error :**

```
18/01/08 15:34:36 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python2.7
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to process 1GB file using pyspark, then as a result my application crashes and I face Java heap space.

How do I look at solving that

Comment: Are you running the 32 bit in your local machine. its not always due to Ram issue check if you are python can be able acquire that much of space it required .

Comment: i am runing 64 bit ubuntu machine only